# Mail feature in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have used `MFMailComposeViewController` to implement email functionality in my app. It is working on the iPhone but not on the iPad. What can be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: There is same method for both iphone & ipad.I know it solved but you can check my answer for your knowledge.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798710/not-receiving-attachment-sent-from-ios-app-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/8815433#8815433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is no email account set up on the iPad. Try to check that by using `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` before presenting your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Sanity Check for mail sending

```
BOOL canSendmail = [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];

    if (canSendmail) {
        NSLog(@"EmailPhoto can send");
    [self displayMailComposerSheet];
    }
```