# Not receiving attachment sent from iOS app / MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using `MFMailComposeViewController` to send attachments (pdfs) from within the app. However I am not receiving the attachments when I test this on a device. Any idea what can be the problem?

```
- (void) emailDocument 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pdfURL];


    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailController setSubject:[self title]];
    [mailController setMessageBody:@"Please find the attached documents." isHTML:YES];
    [mailController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"document"];
    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure pdfURL is a valid URL on the device? Please add the code where you assign the pdfURL ivar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to understand this code,it helps u.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])

    myButton.enabled = YES;
}


- (IBAction)buttonPressed 
{
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailController setSubject:@"Hello iPhone"];

    [mailController setMessageBody:@"This is the MailSend Application...." isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];

    [mailController release];
}  

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
[self becomeFirstResponder];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue where mail would be sent sometimes, but not always.  It turned out this was actually a problem with my email account in the Mail app on my iPhone.  To fix, I did the following:

1. Delete your mail account from your iPhone.
2. Re-add the mail account
3. Reboot your phone - I think this was crucial as it caused some syncing between my mail account and the device.

After those 3 steps, mail magically started sending consistently again from my app.